# N size for not being considerated leverage

Tags: regression, linear-model, leverage

Suposse I have a dataset with two variables x and y, with the purpose to run a linear regression y ~ x.
We have all x values equal and y varying between 1 and 10.
For example (in R code):

```
x <- rep(100, 50)
y <- runif(50, 1, 10)
```

If I add a new value, being x value 75, this new value will be considerated a leverage:

```
x <- c(x, 75)
y <- c(y, runif(1, 1, 10))
fit <- lm(y ~ x)
im <- influence.measures(fit)
tail(im$is.inf)
```

How many 75's I need to add to the dataset for not being considerated a leverage?

Comment: Just make a loop in R, experiment, and tell us what you found by answering your question yourself!  Use plots ...

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen finally I made that loop and can get that number of observations.

Comment: Then please show us what you did by answering your Q yourself!